3kW Heater Regulator
I want to build a triac based regulator to bring a 220VAC 3kW (measured 3.5kW on 230VAC) water heater down to 1kw, I plan on replacing triac on a fan regulator circuit to a better one but I am confused about the triacs capability of handling such loads, my options are

BTA41-600B
BTA40-700B
BTA60-1000B

They all appear capable according to datasheet but don't physically look capable of handling close to 20A at max, I can limit max current by pre populating fix resistors so they never have to handle such currents but I want to be on the safe side,
Commerical solutions are more expensive then replacing the heater as it's brand new and can be replaced without additional cost.
I would like to retain ability to have more power if I want because water heater also have a gas burner that is primarily used and I just got electric heating element installed in it,changing between the two or combining them saves me cost. Also gas is not available 24/7.
I also have the doubts about using existing circuits and swapping the triac, do bigger triacs need bulkier drive signals?

BTA41600 doesn't seem to exist as a part number. Did you mean BTA41-600B?

@ChesterGillon yes, fixed, thanks

Does the heater have multiple heating elements that could be wired in series to reduce power, as would be the case for a two or three phase heater? Are you in the US with access to 120 and 240V? In this case reducing voltage would also reduce power accordingly.

@bobflux it's a single element and we only have 220V

Not quite what you are asking, but a very simple solution would be to add a rectifier, which would reduce the power to half without adding a lot of nasty 100Hz bursts of EMI to your environment (it would unbalance the load which is a bit naughty but I suspect you'll get away with it). You can add a snubber across the rectifier to help with EMI from reverse recovery.
For a triac - power semiconductors are prone to failing 'on'. Assuming that's not an issue (safety or potential material damage-wise) in this case, you should still overrate the part considerably and provide a fairly good size heat sink for the 5W or so dissipation (keep the junction temperature well below 100'C in normal operation for good life).
I don't know what prices are like where you are, but I see BTA60-1500 in a TO3P package for cheap, and that looks pretty good to me. You might also want to consider some thyristor in an isolated package though.
TL;DR: Overrate the part as much as practical and use a big heat sink.

I also had the idea of a rectifier but the wiring in that house is not good, already had to estinguish a fire when testing the heater on first run hence the need of a triac

Can you help me with the last part of the question? I will test it first on room heater but don't want to build something that was never supposed to work

The trigger currents are listed in the datasheet . They're not radically higher for bigger triacs, though you should particularly avoid Q-IV (that's the one with MT2- and Gate+)- many larger triacs are not even guaranteed to trigger in Q-IV. However-- regarding your comments-- please refer to my 2nd paragraph in the original answer. Who is going to extinguish the fire when that triac fails 'on' after a thunderstorm or transient? I strongly advise you to go buy the proper heater and return, sell or discard the one you have - and to have the smaller heater wired up safely.

I took your advice and replaced it with 1.5kW, also replaced wiring with proper sizes and breakers, now I have the choice of running it at max or build the dimmer which can happily fail in 'on' state if it wants, thanks
